# paypal PHP IPN.php file

Tags: php, paypal

hi i am working on Paypal with php.
didn't fined what is the use of

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="ipn.php" />
```

Need Some help

i have downloaded the sample code of inp.php
the code needs

```
mail('YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS', 'Verified IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
```

what that "Verified IPN" means ?
do i need to change things there ?

Followng is the code of my ipn.php file

```
<?php

ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'/ipn_errors.log');


// instantiate the IpnListener class
include('../ipnlistener.php');
$listener = new IpnListener();

$listener->use_sandbox = true;


try {
   $listener->requirePostMethod();
   $verified = $listener->processIpn();
} catch (Exception $e) {
   error_log($e->getMessage());
   exit(0);
}



if ($verified) {

   mail('YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS', 'Verified IPN', $listener->getTextReport());

} else {

   mail('YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS', 'Invalid IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get full understanding on below article for paypal IPN. IPN is secure method for paypal transactions for eCommerce websites.

http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html

Answer (score 0):

IPN is basically a notification-response whenever there's a new transaction coming in, into your PayPal account.

You can specify an URL, where all the IPN response arte going to be directed.

Whenever you get a notification, you need confirm it by sending an HTTP POST to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

And PayPal will respond back - either with "VERIFIED" or "INVALID"

Please follow this link: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside
It will help you understand more about PayPal's IPN.

Thank you.